# Removing a single dependency via USE flag in Gentoo

Tags: pulseaudio, gentoo, dependencies, emerge

I have a system whose sound is currently pulseaudio-{dis,en}abled, and I'm trying to remove pulseaudio.

I first ran a

```
emerge --update --newuse --deep @world
```

and that worked fine.

Then I added "-pulseaudio" to the USE variable in /etc/portage/make.conf.

Currently,

```
localhost /etc/portage # grep -ir 'pulse' *
make.conf:USE="acl alsa apparmor bash-completion berkdb bindist blas bzip2 cairo cjk crypt curl cxx dbus dga doc dri examples ftp gd gif gmp gtk gnome gnuplot gsl gtk gzip icu introspection java jpeg lapck latex mmap modules mp3 mp4 mpeg ncurses offensive ogg openal opengl orc pcre pdf perl php png posix postgres postscript python readline sasl sdl smp sockets sound source spell sqlite ssl static-libs subversion systemd threads truetype udev unicode usb vim-syntax vorbis webkit webp wifi xattr xinerama xml xscreensaver xvid zip zlib X Xaw3d -consolekit -kde -kerberos -ldap -nss -plasma -qt3support -qt4 -qt5 -pulseaudio"
```

Great, but now when I run the above rebuild world command again, nothing gets rebuilt.  And some stuff does actually depend directly on pulseaudio still, so --depclean won't remove it:

```
localhost /etc/portage # equery d pulseaudio
* These packages depend on pulseaudio:
app-emulation/qemu-4.0.0-r50 (pulseaudio ? media-sound/pulseaudio)
gnome-base/gnome-control-center-3.30.3-r1 (>=media-sound/pulseaudio-2.0[glib])
gnome-base/gnome-settings-daemon-3.30.2-r1 (>=media-sound/pulseaudio-2[glib])
 ... (lots of others)
```

portaudio is not explicitly selected:

```
localhost /etc/portage # grep pulseaudio /var/lib/portage/world
```

returns no output.

What am I doing wrong here?  How do I get that dependency to go away?

`emerge --info` at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Emurd1Sb).

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `grep pulseaudio /var/lib/portage/world`?

Comment: It's certainly not in the world root set.  (And if it were selected I'd expect the packages depending on it to still recompile!) Edited above.

Comment: Additionally since then,  I've tried --changed-use instead of --newuse, some more stuff was reinstalled but not the portaudio dependencies.

Comment: Can USE flags somehow imply other USE flags?

Comment: I agree, I don't understand why you're seeing that behavior.  Just for kicks, does `USE="-pulseaudio" emerge -uDNp @world` show that it would trigger the expected rebuild?

Comment: Nope.   =/  `emerge -p --reinstall-atoms \`equery d pulseaudio\` --newuse --deep @world`  gets some more of them, however.   So I'm trying that now...

Comment: annnnnnd it rebuilt them with (pulseaudio).   I'm out of ideas.

Comment: the parenthesis indicate that pulse audio is required.  What profile is selected when issuing `eselect profile list`?